# How do you decode interlaced S24_3LE from ALSA C++ API?

Tags: c++, alsa, pcm

I am doing acoustic research and need to get waveforms from several mics.

I have a Steinberg UR44 which records in S24_3LE. It has 6 channels.
I know that per sample it generates 3 bytes, and that all 6 channels is encoded in these 3 bytes. But I have no idea what bit operations need to be done in order to separate the channels and get usable waveforms.

I'm fully capable of capturing and playing with the `snd_pcm_readi` and `snd_pcm_writei` functions. But can't make heads or tails of the 3 byte bit format.

PS if you can recommend any books on audio programming, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that all channels are compressed into a single sample?

Comment: I was just looking at raw data put out per second. I rechecked this. It looks like 3 bytes per channel. I guess the phrase is "per frame 6 channels * 3 byte/per sample = 18 bytes." Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, channels are separate.